# Comparer for Double and Decimal

Tags: c#

I created the following Double comparer to compare 2 doubles with precision:

```
  class DoubleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Double> {

    private readonly int _precision;

    public DoubleComparer(int precision)
    {
        _precision = precision;
    }

    public bool Equals(double x, double y)
    {
        return Double.Equals(Math.Round(x, _precision), Math.Round(y, _precision));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double obj)
    {
       return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

  }
```

I would also like to compare Decimals.

Can I create one Comparer that could handle Double and Decimal?

Or do I need two?

Comment: `class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<double>, IEqualityComparer<decimal>`? You'll need separte `Equals(double x, double y)` and `Equals(decimal x, decimal y)` methods, ec, of course

Comment: Note that `Double.Equals` is just `Object.Equals` since `Double` has no separate `static` method. Consider using `Math.Round(x, _precision).Equals(Math.Round(y, _precision))` instead to avoid boxing.

Comment: Or just `==` -- it's what you'd normally use to compare doubles

Comment: There are a lot of reasons to wag a finger at funky math like this.  You can't use Double.Equals() to reliably test for equality, Math.Round() does *not* fix that.  But okay for Decimal.Equals().  How would you explain to a baffled user that, say, 1.51 is equal to 2.49 but 2.49 is not equal to 2.51?

Comment: @HansPassant The objective is when precision = 2 then 2.492 equals 2.493 because I am considering only 2 floating points. Am I missing something?

Comment: The normal way is to find the absolute difference between your two doubles, then check whether it's below some delta

Comment: @canton7 I was following XUnit's Assert.Equal with precision. They use  Math.Round: https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/58a59628853ed7a63895945fdac7984a92da2343/EqualityAsserts.cs#L135

Comment: It is wrong, the one below it is correct.  Consider Math.Pow(10, -precision) if needed to get a usable tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just implement more than one interface. For example:

```
class DecimalAndDoubleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Double>, IEqualityComparer<decimal>
{

    private readonly int _precision;

    public DecimalAndDoubleComparer(int precision)
    {
        _precision = precision;
    }

    public bool Equals(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Round(x, _precision) == Math.Round(y, _precision);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        return Math.Round(x, _precision) == Math.Round(y, _precision);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(decimal obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```